# Can't print breadcrumb

Tags: theming

I'm trying to move the breadcrumb from one part of my theme to another, and they have different template files (using an Omega subtheme). $breadcrumb seems to be an array. I've tried l($breadcrumb) and theme($breadcrumb) to no avail. How do you print out a properly themed and string-ified breadcrumb in a template?

Here's my code btw.

```
<?php 
function rescue_breadcrumb($variables) {
    $breadcrumb = $variables['breadcrumb'];
    if (!empty($breadcrumb)) {
    $crumbs = '<ul class="breadcrumbs">';
    foreach($breadcrumb as $value) {
       $crumbs .= '<li>'.$value.'</li>';
       }
       $crumbs .= '</ul>';
    }
      return $crumbs;
  }
$breadcrumb = drupal_get_breadcrumb();
if ($breadcrumb): ?>
  <div id="breadcrumb" class="grid-<?php print $columns; ?>"><?php print $breadcrumb; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`theme_breadcrumb()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_breadcrumb/7) would probably be the best choice:

```
print theme('breadcrumb', array('breadcrumb' => $breadcrumb));
```

It expects the `breadcrumb` variable to be an array, each item of which makes up one part of the breadcrumb trail. So this array:

```
$breadcrumb[] = l('Home', '<front>');
$breadcrumb[] = l('Page', 'page');
$breadcrumb[] = l('Subpage', 'page/subpage');
```

will produce:

```
Home > Page > Subpage
```

You can also use plain text instead of links for the breadcrumb items in case you need to.